# How to prove this function is injective using only the definition?

Tags: calculus, functions

Let $f(x) = 2x + \frac{8}{x}$. And let the domain be $(5,9]$. How can I see that this is an injective function?

We have injectivity only iff $f(a)=f(b) \Rightarrow a=b $. In our case we have
$$
f(a)=f(b) \Rightarrow 2a + 8/a = 2b+8/b
$$
but how can we conclude that $a=b$? Sure, we know that the function is increasing monotonically but let's not use this fact.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: 
\begin{align}
2(a-b)+8\left(\frac{1}{a}-\frac{1}{b}\right) = 2(a-b)\left(1+\frac{4}{ab}\right)= 0
\end{align}